# Ubuntu 14.04 second monitor's screen overflowing

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

Im seeking help with this very weird issue. I have been using my ubuntu 14.04 with an extra monitor for quite q while now with no problem, although when I turned my laptop on today, the linked picture shows how my monitors looked. Somehow the second screen is overflowing on the right side and continues on the left side. The reason why I didn't post a print screen is that it displays correctly on the print. Although Im sure its not a monitor issue, because if I display the screen only on the monitor it looks fine.

Any idea?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QJdxN5S.jpg]

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information on your hardware?  What GPU are you using? What driver version?  If you don't know how to provide these, just leave a comment, otherwise you're going to attract low-quality answers...

Comment: Its a Samsung rf-511 laptop with NVIDIA GeForce GT540M (Optimus). Im not sure about the driver, but it should be the default. But I didn't mess around with it. it was working before.

Comment: `nvidia-settings --version` ?

Comment: nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Comment: How technical are you?

Comment: Web developer, basic ubuntu... I use it for LAMP

Comment: I'll be adding an answer in the next few minutes.  As you're a developer you should be acquainted with rolling back to a previous version...  ;-)

Comment: I would really appreciate that :) Thanks already!

Comment: Don't thank me!  If it works, please accept the answer by clicking the grey check-mark icon below 0 (turning it green)  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check running the below command from your terminal window and see whether this helps,

**Resetting an out-of-range resolution**

```
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

**You can direct xrandr to set a different resolution like this:**

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768
$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it did not seem to help :S I even rebooted. I use LVDS1 and HDMI1... I set the proper resolutions too... nothing changed unfortunately. Although rm ~/.config/monitors.xml did delete the file, but it still didnt get recreated after reboot... Isnt this weird?

Answer (score 0):

I have to same problem too.
It seems to happen after the latest Nvidia update.
Anyhow I tried the following and that worked for me:

1. Go to Nvidia control panel (e.g Nvidia X server setting)
2. Go to PRIME Profiles tab and select "Intel(Power saving mode)" instead of NVIDIA(Performance Mode).

I don't really understand what was happening, hope something ask give us a better answer.

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem, merely a work-around.  What you did was de-activate the NVidia card.

Comment: Yes definitely this is not a real solution. Do you have any idea on how to investigate the root of the problem?

Comment: Depends on how technical you are...  I have a solution, but it's cutting edge.  Please describe your technical expertise...  (definitely not for newbies)

Comment: Thanks Fabby, I see what you did there. User286678, I use ubuntu for LAMP stack, I know some stuff, not an expert, but please have a try.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.

Comment: Ill have a go with this asap. should i try installing version 331.113-0ubuntu1~xedgers15.04.1 u think?

Comment: That's the problem.  From now on, you're on your own.  I've been using them for 6 months now and am *currently* using version 346.22 and very happy with it!  Try to install the whole (as advertised) and not individual ones as then you can pick and choose (as some things will become better with newer versions, but other things might become worse and then you'll have to roll back!)